# Understanding the methods of DatabaseMetaData

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, metadata

I am using MySql, JDBC, Java to make my code. I am unable to understand what some terms in the API mean. It is preventing me from doing the work below-
To make code that checks if a particular DB exists, then checks if a particular table DB exists in that DB, followed by a particular column in that table.

Each table description has the following columns:

```
TABLE_CAT String => table catalog (may be null)
TABLE_SCHEM String => table schema (may be null)
TABLE_NAME String => table name
TABLE_TYPE String => table type. Typical types are "TABLE", "VIEW", "SYSTEM     TABLE",     "GLOBAL TEMPORARY", "LOCAL TEMPORARY", "ALIAS", "SYNONYM".
REMARKS String => explanatory comment on the table
TYPE_CAT String => the types catalog (may be null)
TYPE_SCHEM String => the types schema (may be null)
TYPE_NAME String => type name (may be null)
SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME String => name of the designated "identifier" column of a typed table (may be null)
REF_GENERATION String => specifies how values in SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME are  created.      
Values are "SYSTEM", "USER", "DERIVED". (may be null)
```

What is a table catalog, what is a table schema, SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j.html) implementation of [DatabaseMetadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) is concerned `TABLE_CAT` returns the database name (as in [CREATE DATABASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-database.html)); `TABLE_SCHEM` is `null` and `SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME` is not returned.

This is database and driver specific. As an example, Oracle [ojdbc drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) will return `null` for `TABLE_CAT` and the object owner for `TABLE_SCHEM`.

---

For your particular task (MySQL + Connector/J):

1. To check if a particular database exists → Use `getCatalogs()` to obtain a `ResultSet`, iterate its rows and retrieve the `TABLE_CAT` column, your database should match one of its values.
2. To check if the database contains a particular table → `getTables(databaseName, null, tableName, new String[]{"TABLE"})` should return a non empty `ResultSet`.
3. To check if the table contains a particular column → `getColumns(databaseName, null, tableName, columnName)` should return a non empty `ResultSet`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Can you also explain what the other terms mean (such as REMARKS, REF_GENERATION etc...) and what is their purpose ?

Comment: At least in my environment (MySQL 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 + mysql-connector-java-5.1.21) `REF_GENERATION` and `TYPE_*` are not returned by getTables. `REMARKS` will bring the table comment, but only if `useInformationSchema` is set to `true` in the connection properties

Comment: Where can I get some more info about the meaning of these things ?

Comment: Since it is pretty much database/driver specific, and, to the best of my knowledge, no in deep documentation about it exists, I would try digging into [Connector/J source code](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/sources.html), specially [DatabaseMetaData](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mark-mysql/connectorj/5.1/view/head:/src/com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData.java) and [DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mark-mysql/connectorj/5.1/view/head:/src/com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.java).

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony ! Hope to learn more from you. :)